# Bidirectional connection for a Minesweeper's Field and Cell

Tags: rust, software-design

I keep working on my implementation of the Minesweeper game in Rust.

What I've got at the moment, is the working code to create a field, populate the field with cells and randomly distribute the mines.

Here's the `main.rs` file:

```rust
mod field;

fn main() {
    let mut field = field::Field::new(52, 9).expect("Couldn't instantiate the field!");

    field
        .insert_mines(80, Some((3, 6)))
        .expect("Couldn't insert mines!");

    println!("DISPLAY:\n{}", field);
    println!("DEBUG:\n{:?}", field);
}
```

Here's the `field.rs`:

```rust
mod cell;

use cell::CellVariant;
use cell::FieldCell;
use rand::prelude::SliceRandom;
use rand::thread_rng;
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Default, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Field(Vec<Vec<FieldCell>>);

impl Field {
    pub fn new(columns: u8, rows: u8) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        if (columns as u16 * rows as u16) < 2_u16 {
            Err(())
        } else {
            Ok(Field(vec![
                vec![FieldCell::new_empty(); columns as usize];
                rows as usize
            ]))
        }
    }

    pub fn get_size(&self) -> (u8, u8, u16) {
        let columns = self.0.first().map(|r| r.len()).unwrap_or(0) as u8;
        let rows = self.0.len() as u8;
        let size = columns as u16 * rows as u16;

        (columns, rows, size)
    }

    pub fn insert_mines(
        &mut self,
        number_of_mines: u16,
        except: Option<(u8, u8)>,
    ) -> Result<(), ()> {
        // get the width of a single row and the total cells number of the field
        let (columns, rows, total_number_of_cells) = self.get_size();

        if let Some((r, c)) = except {
            if (r > rows - 1) || (c > columns - 1) {
                return Err(());
            }
        }

        // return an error if the required number of mines is less than 1 or is more than the total number of cells
        // minus 1 (there should always be at least one cell without a mine)
        if number_of_mines < 1 || number_of_mines > (total_number_of_cells - 1) {
            return Err(());
        }

        // flatten the field for an easier interaction with it
        let mut flattened_field = self.0.iter_mut().flatten().collect::<Vec<&mut FieldCell>>();

        // return an error if there are mines already: can't populate with mines a field that's already been populated
        if flattened_field
            .iter()
            .any(|cell| matches!(cell.variant, CellVariant::Mine))
        {
            return Err(());
        }

        // remove the reference to the excepted cell (if any) to avoid marking it as mine
        if let Some((r, c)) = except {
            // `r * columns + c` is a formula of getting a 1D flattened-vector's index based on the original 2D vector's
            // coordinates
            flattened_field.remove((r * columns + c) as usize);
        }

        // shuffle the mutable borrowings to randomly distribute the mines
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        flattened_field.shuffle(&mut rng);

        // make the first `number_of_mines` cells mines
        flattened_field
            .iter_mut()
            .take(number_of_mines as usize)
            .for_each(|cell| **cell = FieldCell::new_mine());

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

And here's the `cell.rs`:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum CellVariant {
    Empty(u8),
    Mine,
    _Flag,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum CellState {
    Closed,
    _Open,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct FieldCell {
    pub variant: CellVariant,
    pub state: CellState,
}

impl FieldCell {
    pub fn new_empty() -> Self {
        FieldCell {
            variant: CellVariant::Empty(0),
            state: CellState::Closed,
        }
    }

    pub fn new_mine() -> Self {
        FieldCell {
            variant: CellVariant::Mine,
            state: CellState::Closed,
        }
    }
}
```

As a next step, I'd like to implement populating the field with numbers around the cells with mines. The idea here is pretty basic: take each cell that has a mine, take all of its naighbouring (adjacent) cells and increment each of those cell's number by one.

The problem is, as I understand it, the algorithm won't be very much efficient because of the unidirectional connection of Field -> FieldCell. **What I'd like to do, is to create a bidirectional connection in the form of Field <-> FieldCell**. I believe, that that would make things much easier both for the current task and, potentially, for the future functionality of the game (more on that later).

**So, here comes the question**: is it really worth it? Should there really be a bidirectional connection? Should cells have access to their field?

For comparison, as another option, a `FieldCell` might only save the cell's position (e.g. as an `(u8, u8)` tuple).

As I can see, creating the bidirectional connection might be a good strategy here, because in Minesweeper, each cell needs to be able to interact with its neighboring cells and relay information, such as mine counts. Keeping the relationship unidirectional (where the Field knows about Cells but not vice versa) might make some operations more complex, especially when dealing with cell adjacency and revealing neighboring cells (which, as I can see, is exactly what's needed to implement the numbers insertion).

The potential benefits:

1. Neighbor Interactions: Cells need to be aware of their neighboring Cells to compute mine counts and reveal adjacent cells when an empty cell is clicked.
2. Efficiency in Operations: Operations like revealing neighboring cells or marking flags may require Cells to access information about their neighbors quickly, which a bidirectional relationship facilitates.
3. Enhanced Logic Encapsulation: While encapsulation is valuable, allowing Cells to have access to their Field might enhance the game's logic by simplifying certain operations and improving code readability.

*I'm also stuck with the implementation, but I decided to ask a separate question about it in case we come to the conclusion here that an implementation makes sense at all.*

Comment: [Self referential datastructures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) will very likely *not* make your code simpler/easier, quite the opposite. Your whole post reads like taking off your OOP glasses will make your life much easier.

Comment: @cafce25 The link in your comment is more about a specific issue (like my post is, as well). But maybe you could provide some good reading materials about the second part of your comment (*taking off your OOP glasses will make your life much easier*)? It has become a habit of mine to think about data structures from the OOP perspective, and I'm not really familiar with other concepts existing.

Comment: @cafce25 also, do I uderstand correctly that you're saying that the self-referetial data structures will likely not make my *Rust* code simpler? I mean, from the architectural point of view, is it really not worth it to have such a connection is my specific case? Implementation details specifically in Rust are another story.

Comment: @smellyshovel What they mean is that in OOP you tend to think of the actions you perform on a specific object ("I click a _cell_ which can reveal its neighbors") but that approach will be problematic in Rust, since Rust isn't an OOP language. Consider instead the information you need to process a click of a cell: you need to know the entire game board and you need to know the position of the clicked cell. That's it -- so write a function taking those two things as inputs (`&mut Field` and an x/y pair).

Comment: @smellyshovel The fact that you need a `&mut Field` strongly suggests that perhaps this should be a method on `Field` (and take `&mut self`) instead of being a method on the cell type.

Comment: @cdhowie well, totally makes sense. Will try to implement then and will ask separate more code-specifiec question if I get stuck somewhere. Thanks.